# How do I use shortcuts on Google web apps which conflict with macOS shortcuts?

Tags: google-docs, google, keyboard-shortcuts, mac

When using Google Docs on macOS, the shortcut that Google has for adding a comment seems to be <kbd>⌘⎇M</kbd>, which [happens to be](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) the same system-wide shortcut for minimizing all of the windows of a particular application. Consequently, when using that shortcut, instead of a comment being added, all the browser windows get minimized.

Is there a way to add a comment via a shortcut on macOS?

How do I use shortcuts like these which conflict with, and are overridden by macOS shortcuts?

Comment: make sure you press `Command ⌘ + Option ⌥ + M` **not** `Command ⌘ + M`

Comment: `Command ⌘ + Option ⌥ + M` is a shortcut which *minimizes all the windows from the currently active application*. `Command ⌘ + M` is a shortcut which *minimizes the currently active window*. Both are shortcuts reserved by macOS unless overridden, which Google Docs doesn't not seem to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out how to do it: the option which you are looking for is *Override browser shortcuts*.

Go to Help and search for and enable the following option:

**Override browser shortcuts**

This option can also be toggled by going to the shortcuts screen. There will be a switch for it on the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

yes it is:

- **<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>** + **<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>** + **<kbd>M</kbd>** ...for **Inserting comment**
- **<kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>** + **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**...for **Entering current comment**

all keyboard shortcuts: **[https://support.google.com/docs/](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)**

or type this into search bar: **chrome://extensions/shortcuts**